# How to add custom functions for spreadsheet in my Google appscript addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently developing a Google Appscript addon. It was already published into the Google Workspace Marketplace. I am trying to add some custom functions for spreadsheet in the Workspace Appscript. For example, something like this:

```
 /**
  * Multiplies the input value by 2.
  *
  * @param {number} input The value to multiply.
  * @return The input multiplied by 2.
  * @customfunction
  */

  function DOUBLE(input) {
    return input * 2;
  }
```

But it doesn't work after I deployed it. How could I make it work?

I searched around, but still couldn't find the answer. I see some Google Workspace addon supports these custom functions, not sure how they achieve it.

Thanks!

Comment: [There are two types of add-ons; Google Workspace Add-ons and Editor Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types). IIRC only Editor Add-ons support custom spreadsheet formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the Google App Script you already have:

```
 /**
  * Multiplies the input value by 2.
  *
  * @param {number} input The value to multiply.
  * @return The input multiplied by 2.
  * @customfunction
  */

  function DOUBLE(input) {
    return input * 2;
  }
```

Then, move the script as an add-on. In the script editor, click Extensions-> Manage Extensions. Then create a new add-on and save and then publish.

Install the add-on in Google Sheets, open Google sheet, Extensions-> Manage Extensions, and then search your add-on and install.

Lastly, use the custom function in Google sheets by entering '=DOUBLE(number)' in a cell and it should work.

Comment: "In the script editor, click Extensions-> Manage Extensions.", where is the extensions in the script editor, or do you mean the Deploy->Manage deployments in the script editor? I actually created a new deployment  to public with my code again, but when I enter = DOULBE(number) in the cell, it still doesn't seem working.